# Haxe crashes FlashDevelop (permissions error)

Tags: flashdevelop, haxe, permission-denied

I've been using FlashDevelop for almost two years now, and today I decided to start using Haxe. The only problem was that its installation (or something related to it) completely obliterated FD. It will now launch but, as soon as it has initialized it'll crash. Exceptions.log is:

```
Unhandled exception:

System.Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\WMI\RtBackup' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalGetFileDirectoryNames(String path, String userPathOriginal, String searchPattern, Boolean includeFiles, Boolean includeDirs, SearchOption searchOption)
   at System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(String path, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)
   at System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(String path)
   at ASCompletion.Model.PathExplorer.ExploreFolder(String path, String[] masks)
   at ASCompletion.Model.PathExplorer.ExploreFolder(String path, String[] masks)
   at ASCompletion.Model.PathExplorer.ExploreFolder(String path, String[] masks)
   at ASCompletion.Model.PathExplorer.ExploreFolder(String path, String[] masks)
   at ASCompletion.Model.PathExplorer.BackgroundRun()
   at ASCompletion.Model.PathExplorer.ExploreInBackground()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

This path sometimes is:

```
'C:\Windows\System32\Com\dmp'
```

(Edit)A full reinstall of both FlashDevelop and Haxe, erasing all the %localappdata% (as to have a fresh start), or running as administrator won't work. (/edit)
<del>The only thing that seems to get rid of the crash is uninstalling Haxe completely.</del> Now it'll crash even without Haxe, reporting access denied to `'C:\Windows\System32\Com\dmp'`.
Can anyone help me?
Thank you in advance,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a full reinstallation. Export your config files, uninstall it and reinstall. Also, use the software installation tool from Flashdevelop to install Haxe.

I have never heard of this error before, I hope you solve the problem!

Comment: A full reinstall of both fd and haxe, erasing all the %localappdata% (as to have a fresh start), or running as administrator won't work :/ thank you anyhow!